# Zend: Where/how can I register custom view helpers?

Tags: zend-framework

In my `layout.phtml` file I have :

```
<?php echo $this->Test(); ?>
```

I have created a Test view helper at `application/views/helpers/Test.php`

```
<?php 

class My_View_Helper_Test extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

    public function Test() {
        return 'test';
    }

}
```

And my config file @ `configs/application.ini`:

```
resources.view[] = ''
resources.view.helperPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
```

Error I get:

> Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception:
>   Plugin by name 'Test' was not found in
>   the registry; used paths:
>   Zend_View_Helper_:
>   Zend/View/Helper/:./views/helpers/ in
>   /usr/share/php/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php
>   on line 406

On a similar note I can't register my admin view helper either..

```
resources.view.helperPath.Admin_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/admin/views/helpers"
```

My `modules/admin/views/helpers/AdminPanel.php`:

```
<?php

class My_View_Helper_AdminPanel extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

public function AdminPanel() { return 'test'; }

}
```

Do I have no choice but to do this in the Bootstrap with addHelperPath? If so could someone demonstrate how I would using my paths?

Comment: in your first one, you might want to put a prefix on that helperPath... `resouces.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = `

Comment: Also: `resources.view[] = ''` makes no sense as an INI directive, it might be messing with you...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `application.ini` is probably the best way to define these.  I put all my view helpers inside my library folder:

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
autoloadernamespaces.0 = "SNTrack_"

;  -- Note, these are the only resources.view lines I have...
resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"
resources.view.helperPath.SNTrack_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/SNTrack/View/Helper"
```

Directory structure:

```
/
  application/
  library/
    SNTrack/
      View/
        Helper/
          Test.php
```

View:

```
 $this->test('test')
```

SNTrack/View/Helper/Test.php:

```
 class SNTrack_View_Helper_Test extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
   public function test($args) { return $args; }
 }
```

Comment: I tried what you commented with, `resources.view.helperPaths.My_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"` but it still can't find `Test`. Do you mind posting your working structure, using your ini file only?

Comment: I'm selecting this as the answer because you provided me with the directory structure, although the way I actually solved it was by moving my bootstrap function which added encoding/doctype to the view at the start, before my other init methods and that somehow fixed it.

Comment: @meder - You should be able to remove any doctype/encoding/etc stuff from the bootstrap all together, replacing it with proper configuration directives (which I'm pretty sure using the `[]` trick doesn't work in INI's) -- If you find that it isn't loading your settings quick enough `$this->boostrap('view');` at the top of your `_initApp()` function in your bootstrap should read/set all the settings then.

Answer (score 1):

in my bootstrap:

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->addHelperPath(DE_Config::get('DE_appDir').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'lib'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'DE'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'View'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Helper'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'DE_View_Helper');
$viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
$viewRenderer->setView($view);
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
```

Comment: The DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant is great for performing an explode() on file paths, but is unnecessary for specifying an include path.  Forward slashes work fine in Windows and *nix platforms.  (Just an FYI)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this exact problem, and realised it was due to a problem in my bootstrap: I was defining and using a new Zend_View object in one of my _init functions, which I think was overwriting all my other view settings from both my bootstrap and my application.ini file (including my resources.view.helperPath definition). The offending code had been blindly copied from [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zendx.jquery.view.html), and placed into an _initJQuery() function in my bootstrap, which looked like this:

```
protected function _initJQuery() {
   $view = new Zend_View();
   $view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');

   $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
   $viewRenderer->setView($view);
   Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
}
```

The solution was to replace the first line ($view = new Zend_View()) with this:

```
$this->bootstrap('view');
$view = $this->getResource('view');
```

Another thing to bare in mind, regarding your line:

> resources.view.helperPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"

Note that this only registers the path, and not the class prefix, so this will only work if the helper classes have the default Zend class prefix of Zend_View_Helper i.e. Zend_View_Helper_Test. If you want the class to be My_View_Helper_Test, then you need to do this:

> resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"